# Can't user Wait function with find by mobile element

Tags: java, selenium, junit, appium, webdriverwait

I am locating elements by Findby and then using a wait function to throw an error if the element doesn't exist but appium gets stuck searching for the elements and keeps giving nosuchelementerror infinitely
here is my code:

```
@FindBy(id = "tv_error_card")
MobileElement NID_Card_Error;
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 5000);

if(wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOf(NID_Card_Error)) == null) {
            System.out.println("time expired");
            assertTrue("element messing ", false);
        }
```

I know I can use wait with a by locator but I am trying to do it with mobile element

Answer (score 0):

Its working as expected only. `visibilityOf` condition is looking for the element for the given time and throwing `NoSuchElementException` if not found. You need to `catch` the exception and perform the steps what you need. You need to use `try-catch` like below,

```
try {
    wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOf(NID_Card_Error));
} catch (org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException e) {
    System.out.println("time expired");
    assertTrue("element messing ", false);
}
```

Comment: I have tried this approach but it's still stuck

Comment: What error you are getting?

Comment: [W3C] Matched W3C error code 'no such element' to NoSuchElementError
[W3C (c61c8bb3)] Encountered internal error running command: NoSuchElementError: An element could not be located on the page using the given search parameters.

even though I am currently trying with :
try{
    wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.id("tv_error_card")));
    
   }catch(Exception e){
    System.out.println("time expired");
    assertTrue("element messing ", false);
   }

Comment: Is `System.out.println("time expired");` executed?

Comment: no appium gets stuck at the wait function

Comment: It's not stuck. The element what you are looking is not available so the scripts waits for the given amount of time and throwing the error message. I am not sure why the exception is not being captured. Can you try this `catch Exception e) {System.out.println("time expired");
    assertTrue("element messing ", false);}`